# How do I prevent a vector from ever changing size?

Tags: class, visual-c++, memory-management, stdvector

First off, I want to gain a better understanding on vectors. So,

1. How does a vector change size?
2. What enables the vector to change size?
3. If a class is used in a vector, how does the vector call that class's constructors/destructor? (Please give more information than necessary on this one, I'm not sure I asked the question properly).
4. When an element of a vector is removed, the vector is completely ridden of that element, correct?  If not, what happens instead?
5. If I'm using a class in a vector, how do I call individual elements' destructors and set those individual elements to NULL without changing the size of the vector by getting rid of those elements?  (I want certain elements to act as placeholders so that I have a spot in the vector without having to allocate the class.  The vector will never exceed a given size).  Ultimately, how do I prevent the vector from ever changing size while being able to manage my memory effectively?

Please be as informative and descriptive as you can so I can get a better understanding of vectors and use them to my advantage.

Comment: too many questions...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I suppose I could find the answers to the first four elsewhere on my own time.  I can't seem to find the answer to number 5 anywhere though....

Comment: Use std::array instead of std::vector if you want a fixed size.

Comment: @PaulR What if I want to be able to delete elements in the middle of the array?  Won't that cause memory issues?

Comment: "Never change size" and "want to delete elements" sound like contradicting goals.

Comment: `how do I call individual elements' destructors and set those individual elements to NULL` This question doesn't make sense. Objects of class type have destructors, but you can't set one of those to `NULL`. You can set a pointer to `NULL`, but pointers don't have destructors. So, what is the element type of the hypothetical container you want to work with?